# Can you replace between two words? - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I got this list and I want to replace everything between ".gif" with the number on the other side

".gif" needs to replaced with everything between > and .gif on the same line

So you got ".gif" and FI6 on the same line
Change that to "FI6.gif"

Here is a picture
[image]

The reason is that there are **MANY, VERY MANY** of them. (4423)

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regular expression find and replace.

Find: `<img src="\.gif" alt="\.gif"> <a href="(.*)gif">(.*)gif</a>`

Replace with `<img src="\1gif" alt="\1gif"> <a href="\1gif">\2gif</a>`

Check search mode `Regular Expression` in the search dialog and click `Replace all`

Comment: I think it worked! I say i think becaus it crashes my notepad++...

Comment: I there a way to split the file in 20 parts becaus this is to much for the programme and the site to handle

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are the same all the way down as in this:

[image]

Then I could record a macro to do it.

In Notepad++ what you need to do is position your typing cursor at the beginning of the first line then with the keyboard make the change you want so:

You'll need to record the macro then use the right arrow to go all the way to the beginning of FI3.gif then using shift select this section and copy using CTRL + C

Use left arrow to go back to where you want this writing and paste using CTRL + V then move on to the next line and position the typing cursor at the beginning again.

Then stop the macro recording and let it play through the document it should then complete it for you.

I use it a lot and its quite rock solid.

Can explain in more detail if needed but have a little go and see how you get on.